# Remove single line breaks but keep empty lines with Vim

Tags: vim, text, line-breaks

Is it possible to remove single line breaks but to keep empty lines (double line breaks I guess?) in Vim? I'm using Vim's HardPencil plugin to do some word processing, and I like the hard line breaks because it makes it easier to bounce around the file. However, I need to share this information in LibreOffice Writer or Word, and hard line breaks won't work well if others edit the file. To clarify, this is what I have:

```
Line1.
Line2.
Line3.

Line4.
Line5.
```

And this is what I would like:

```
Line1. Line2. Line3.

Line4. Line5.
```

Essentially hard line breaks should be replaced with a space, and double line breaks should be preserved.

I've tried variations of `:%s/\n` but can't get the double line breaks to be preserved. I've found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464735/remove-single-line-breaks-keep-empty-lines) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170112/how-do-i-remove-single-line-breaks), but these are not Vim specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace `line+line break` with just `line`, and use negative look ahead `\(\n\)\@!` to make sure it's not followed by an empty line:

```
:%s/\(.\+\)\n\(\n\)\@!/\1 /
```

@Peter_Rincker's cleaner solution:

```
:%s/.\+\zs\n\ze./ /
```

Comment: I think this is really close. `Line1. Line2. Line3.` all appear on the same line appropriately, as does `Line4. Line5.`, but the blank line between the two has been collapsed.

Comment: Subsequently, I guess I could add a blank line after each line break?

Comment: @haff, i missed that. i guess you can use negative look ahead here, but the regex gets a little complicated

Comment: We can make it a bit easier to read without the negative look-behind by using `\zs` and `\ze`. As a bonus it is also shorter. e.g. `:%s/.\+\zs\n\ze./ /`

Comment: @PeterRincker, wow, wasn't aware of `\zs \ze`. very useful. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use `gw` (or `gq`) with a motion (like `G`).

```
gwG
```

`gw` is Vim's paragraph formatting operator which "reflows" text to the desired `'textwidth'`. You may want to temporarily set `'textwidth'` to `0` for unlimited text width (`:set tw=0`).

There some other ways as well do this as well:

- Use `:%!fmt`- same idea as above but use `fmt` external tool and a filter.
- `:v/^$/,//-j` - squeezes non-empty lines together. Fails if the end of the range does not have a blank line
- `:g/\v(.+\zs\n)+/,-//j` - Also squeezes non-empty lines together, but avoids the range error of the previous method.
- A substitution - See @Fabricator solution for an example

For more help see:

```
:h gw
:h operator
:h 'tw'
:h filter
:h :range!
:h :range
:h :v
:h :j
:h :g
:h magic
:h /\zs
```