# Remove single line breaks but keep empty lines

Tags: python, line-breaks

There is already a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283960/remove-single-line-breaks-but-keep-empty-lines-with-vim), but I would like to use python, not Vim.

I want to remove single line breaks but to keep empty lines,

```
This is a test. 
This 
is a test.

This is a test. 
This is a 
test.
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
This is a test. This is a test

This is a test. This is a test
```

I am using a code to replace texts, I would like to know if it is possible to adapt it...

```
import os
texttofind = ''
texttoreplace = ''
sourcepath = os.listdir('InputFiles/')

for file in sourcepath:
    inputfile = 'InputFiles/' + file
    print('Conversion is ongoing for:' + inputfile)
    with open(inputfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
        filedata = inputfile.read()
        freq = 0
        freq = filedata.count(texttofind)
    destinationpath = 'OutputFile/' + file
    filedata = filedata.replace(texttofind, texttoreplace)
    with open(destinationpath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
    print('Total %d Record Replaced' % freq)
```

If i use `texttofind = '\n'` the empty lines will also be replaced... Maybe a modification in the `for` to ignore empty lines, but I don't know how to do that, could anyone help?

Comment: You have to use this regex of `\n` which is not follows by `\n`. The required one is this if I'm not mistaken: `\n(?=\n)`

Comment: @Hamed_gibago It still keeps removing the empty lines... even using Wiktor Stribiżew's answer

Comment: @Mrcrg Wiktor's answer worked for me when I just used a blank substitution, not a space.